# BOM vs explicit encoding declaration in XML

Tags: xml, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-16

Just wondering why XML uses an explicit encoding declaration. For me it looks like a strange design.
Consider an UTF-16 encoding declaration(see example). Doesn't a BOM at the beginning of the stream/file make this obsolete? What happens if a BOM indicates UTF-16 and the explicit encoding declaration is set as UTF-8? Does that even make any sense?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
```

Comment: Note that it is perfectly legal (and often sensible, I guess) to omit the encoding declaration part of the XML declaration. In that case it simply looks like **`<?xml version="1.0"?>`**. In many cases the encoding is known already from other sources, or can be correctly inferred automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How would you distinguish an ISO-8859-1 encoded document from an ISO-8859-2 encoded document? There is no BOM at all and you can't infer the encoding without an XML declaration saying which encoding was used. If XML allowed only UTF-8 and UTF-16 then a BOM based detection might have sufficed although I think that I remember early XML parsers in the Java world being challenged by an UTF-8 BOM.
So basically, to support a great number of encodings, the XML declaration is needed to declare the used encoding.

Comment: However, as I also commented above, it is also legal for the XML declaration to omit the encoding declaration part: `<?xml version="1.0"?>`

Answer (score 2):

There are a vast number of problems reported on StackOverflow caused by reading data in the wrong encoding. Sadly, when you read a file from filestore, or get a message via some protocol such as HTTP, there is often no encoding information available, and when there is, it is often unreliable. Putting the encoding in the header of the file is just one pragmatic and imperfect attempt to solve this problem (the BOM is another). It's not the whole answer (because for example it's very easy for non-XML-aware processes such as a file transfer operation to change the encoding without changing the XML declaration), but it helps.